# Ghost4J/Ghostscript - Getting error 100 when trying to embed fonts into PDF

Tags: java, c, ghostscript

I have PDFs with referenced fonts and I would like to use Ghost4J to output PDFs containing embedded fonts.

```
public void execute() {
    Ghostscript gs = Ghostscript.getInstance();
    String[] cmdStr={
        "-dNOPAUSE","-dBATCH","-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4",
        "-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress","-dSAFER","-dNOPLATFONTS",
        "-sDEVICE=display","-sPAPERSIZE=letter",
        "-I","C:\\WINNT\\Fonts\\;C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.05\\lib\\;C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.05\\bin\\;",
        "-dSubsetFonts=true","-dEmbedAllFonts=true",
        "-sFONTPATH=C:\\WINNT\\Fonts", "-sOutputFile=",
        outputPath,"-c",".setpdfwrite", "-f",inputPath
    };      
    try {

        gs.initialize(cmdStr);
        gs.exit();

    } catch (GhostscriptException e) {          
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When running any PDF I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot initialize Ghostscript interpreter. Error code is -100
```

When run on the command line the arguments work correctly.

```
gswin32c.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dSafer -NOPLATFONTS -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sFONTPATH=C:\\WINNT\\Fonts -sOutputFile=c:\out.pdf -f c:\test.pdf
```

**Follow-ups:**

- GhostScript has permission to write to C:.
- I have removed all of the switches except outputPath, "-f",inputPath and I still get the error
- Removed comma at end of cmdStr after inputPath

**Notes:**

- I am working on getting the callbacks

Comment: I don't know anything about Ghost4J, but.... these parameters `-ps2pdf` and `-psconv` don't look familiar to me for a Ghostscript command line. Also, I don't see any call to `gswin32c.exe` which would work on Windows (only `gs` which would work on Unix) in your code example's cmdStr...

Comment: Ghost4J is just a Java wrapper for the C++ Ghostscript code. http://ghost4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I guessed so much... But are you sure your way to call Ghostscript from your Java code is correct?

Comment: The first example is very similar to my situation. http://ghost4j.sourceforge.net/coreapisamples.html

Comment: First thing you need to do is capture the back channel information returned by Ghostscript. I have no idea how you would do this in Ghost4J but you absolutely need it. This may tell you what is going wrong. My guess would be it is the OutputFile, are you sure you have permissions to write to the root of C: ? If I were investigating this I would start by cutting the number of parameters down to the minimum. The earlier comment about the unfamiliar parameters is quite correct, these are not normal GS parameters and (in a normal build of GS) will do nothing.

Comment: Thanks see the edits. I am working on getting the callbacks.

Comment: Hi @eabraham, Did you get an answer to this query ?
I am also having the very same issue. new to ghost script :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma after your inputPath variable. This is invalid Java syntax.

I use ghostscript in a production java application to produce PCL files from PDFs. I used the java.lang.Runtime class to execute the Ghostscript executable so I can't give advice directly for Ghost4J.

I suspect that the issue is that the api does not know the location of the supporting files. Try passing the full path of the fonts, lib and bin locations like the following.

```
"-Ic:\Program Files (x86)\gs\fonts\;c:\Program Files (x86)\gs\lib\;c:\Program Files (x86)\gs\bin\;"
```

Comment: You are right about the comma but I am still getting the error message.